# Review history is incomplete

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues

I just saw this today for the first time. After reviewing a post in the "Close Votes" queue, I wanted to see how others had voted on it. When I viewed the queue history, I saw that multiple people had reviewed the same post; however, when I clicked my vote to see the other votes, I only saw my own vote. When I went back to the history page and clicked a different person's vote for the same question, I was able to see the other votes for that question. Clicking my own vote again still only shows my one vote.

I recorded a video of this process. It can viewed at http://sendvid.com/dkpzqx33

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are two different reviews. The post was reviewed by two people. That review was finished. Then the post was sent back to the review queue again where you saw it.

I suspect the first review was cancelled because someone retracted a close vote. So it was dropped from the queue. Then someone added a close vote. So it started in the queue again. A dev would have to confirm this as mods can't see retracted close votes AFAIK. In any event, it's not a bug in the display or in tracking the review history, and in all likelihood not a bug at all.

Comment: quite possible: I did indeed retract my close vote after the question was edited and much improved - and mine was the last close vote left - and if not me someone else retracted a vote because there were 2 at some point, and 0 after I retracted mine cc: @Daniel

Comment: @mbloch That's exactly what I suspected based on your deleted comments. But I had no proof, and wasn't going to reveal your identity anyway.